# Ошибка отображения файлов Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть проект на Django static/media хранятся на облаке Amazon S3, но при переходе по ссылке https://falsehuman-assets.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/media/images/YWVaQgf9JkQ.jpg файл не отображается,настраивал по туториалу описанному здесь https://django.fun/tutorials/dobavlenie-amazon-s3-v-proekt-dzhango/

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить в Bucket policy)

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Имя_вашей_корзины/*"
        }
    ]
}
```